# Changing the Sleep mode activation on the Kindle Paperwhite 10th generation

Tags: power-management, sleep

Is there a way to extend the time before a kindle paperwhite 10th generation goes into sleep mode?

Answer (score 0):

From what i know it's not possible to change that time, but you can disable sleep in general by typing `~ds` in search box and confirming by pressing enter.
Unfortunately only way to get back to default sleep settings is to reboot your Kindle ("Hamburger" menu -> Settings -> "Hamburger" menu -> Restart)
I tested above method on Kindle 7 and Kindle Paperwhite 3, but it should work on other models too.

For older devices (e.g. Classic and Keyboard) you can do this in order to disable screensaver:
`;debugOn`
Press enter
`~disableScreensaver`
Press enter
`;debugOff`
Press enter

And this in order to enable screensaver:
`;debugOn`
Press enter
`~enableScreensaver`
Press enter
`;debugOff`
Press enter